# Runnable executing times two every cron tick

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I know `scheduleProcess` executes once at start.
Then it schedules task to execute with cron every 3. minutes.
After first execution of cron everything is fine.
But every next time there is times two number of invocations of `otherMethod`.
I have made the code easier.

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;

 public void scheduleProcess() {
        Runnable otherMethod = () -> orderSending(); 
        Runnable task = () -> runAs("status", otherMethod);
        scheduledTasks.add(taskScheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("* */3 * * * *")));
    }

public void runAs(String processName, Runnable runnable) {
        System.out.println(processName);
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("test2");
        }
    }

public void orderSending() { // this executes times two every cron tick
        System.out.println("...");
    }
```

Java 8, SpringBoot 2.0.3, running inside tomcat 8 as war.

Comment: How long does it take the task to run?

Comment: About 3-4 seconds. Println with `...` would occur every 3-4 seconds (one time, then two, then four, and so on - I guess).

Comment: @Malt I have managed to find an answer - check it out. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Cron:

```
0 0/3 * * * *
```

Makes the code run as it supposed to.

Cron:

```
* */3 * * * *
```

Made this weird behaviour.